# proc-macro = true breaks VSCode rust-analyser debug lens

Tags: rust, macros, rust-cargo

When I add proc-macro = true to Cargo.toml I am not able to use rust-analyser debug lens on any test in lib.rs anymore. I get:

> error while loading shared libraries: libtest-95a0f3dcb2265cb8.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with rust. Please have a look on this comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24677#issuecomment-95012477

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04.  Rust is installed in the standard way. When I just create lib project with cargo command I can debug the provided test example. Everything is ok. As soon as I add proc-macro = true I get that error.

Comment: Basically I am interested how to debug rust procedural macros. They need a separate lib project. My idea was to write unit tests for macros code and debug them. When you debug the rust code with macros VSCode rust-analyser debugger does not jump into macros code. I know there is cargo expand crate to see generated code.

Comment: can you please show us the output of: `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: looks like I have no value for $LD_LIBRARY_PATH but how proc-macro = true affects that?

Comment: As mentioned in the link above: “Add /usr/local/lib to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or include it in your /etc/ld.so.conf so ldconfig searches it when run).

This doesn't happen just on Arch. Most non-Debian systems don't trust anything outside /lib and /usr/lib by default. Because rustup installs to /usr/local, ldconfig doesn't see the newly installed libraries”.

Comment: I still do not understand how advise from 2015 might help me now. I followed that and the error is the same because I have nothing in my  /usr/local/lib but two Python versions

Comment: I found similar issue and looks like they came to the solution that it is a bug https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_rust/issues/183

Comment: `Executing task: cargo test --package my_proc_macros_lib --lib -- tests --nocapture 

    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.04s
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/my_proc_macros_lib-749dade406800d72)

running 1 test
test tests::it_works ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s`

Comment: Test lens works correctly but Debug lens does not. If that is a bug which bug is it?